# How to make an SWF read result from a PHP?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript

I need to make a SWF that should show some data from the DB. 
The DB will be read using PHP.
I was thinking that the SWF would get the data by accessing "data.php" and data.php will read from the DB. The SWF would read the XML/JSON/RAW DATA from that file and update it's variables.
How can I do this ? any reference maybe ?
Thanks!

Comment: Pranav's solutions is the way to go with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to intercommunicate Flash and PHP is XML (don't forget to use UTF-8!).

in "data.php":

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8'); 
$doc = $xml->appendChild($xml->createElement('my-root-element')); 
... 
header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8'); 
echo $xml->saveXML();
```

In "test.as"

```
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); 
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://.../data.php'); 
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onMyXMLLoad); 
myLoader.load(req); 

function onMyXMLLoad(e:Event) 
{ 
    trace(e.target.data); 
    var xml:XML = new XML(e.target.data); 
    ... 
}
```

Comment: My UTF-8 is read as question marks, would you know how to make flash read it display it right?